# SP Quotation Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can anybody help me with the following line of code. I keep getting the Incorrect syntax near '\' error:

```
 SET @filename = 
 ''BULK INSERT dbo.Tmp_Table 
  FROM ''\\SQL-300\ConvertedFiles\London\Figures\' 
  + @YEAR + '_' + @CLIENT+ '_' + @POLICYID + '.CSV'' 
  WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', KEEPNULLS)''
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SET @filename ='BULK INSERT dbo.Tmp_Table 
  FROM ''\\SQL-300\ConvertedFiles\London\Figures\' 
  + @YEAR + '_' + @CLIENT+ '_' + @POLICYID + '.CSV'' 
  WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = '','', ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'', KEEPNULLS)'
```

Comment: Thanks Vignesh, its this line of code that works perfectly outside of the SP. As soon as I put it inbetween the EXEC(' and ')END it throws the syntax error

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this....

```
DECLARE @filename NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Year     INT;
DECLARE @CLIENT   INT;
DECLARE @PLICYID  INT; 

SET @filename =  N'BULK INSERT dbo.Tmp_Table 
                  FROM ''\\SQL-300\ConvertedFiles\London\Figures\@YEAR_@CLIENT_@POLICYID.CSV '' 
                  WITH 
                    (FIELDTERMINATOR = '',''
                    ,ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
                    ,KEEPNULLS)'

EXECUTE  sp_executesql @filename
                      ,N'@Year INT, @Client INT, @PLICYID INT'
                      ,@Year
                      ,@CLIENT   
                      ,@PLICYID
```

Comment: Thanks M.Ali I tried this and the same syntax error came up. I can't understand it???

Comment: What error message ? just knowing that there is an error message isnt enough to solve it, could you please post the error message you got.

Comment: I may have copied this in wrong but here is my SP from:

Comment: `EXEC('
DECLARE @filename NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Year INT;
DECLARE @CLIENT INT;
DECLARE @POLICYID INT; 
SET @filename =  N''BULK INSERT dbo.Tmp_Table 
                  FROM ''\\\\SQL-300\ConvertedFiles\London\Figures\@YEAR_@CLIENT_@POLICYID.CSV '' 
                  WITH 
                    (FIELDTERMINATOR = '',''
                    ,ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n''
                    ,KEEPNULLS)''
EXECUTE  sp_executesql @filename
                      ,N''@Year INT, @CLIENT INT, @POLICYID INT''
                      ,@Year
                      ,@CLIENT   
                      ,@POLICYID
') END`